# Why does reinterpret_cast<int>(lParam); generate C2440 error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, mfc, reinterpret-cast

I have a typical Windows Message handler for C++/MFC/32-bit with signature
`LRESULT CMyFrame::OnMyMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)`

I have written these two lines, preferring the first over the 2nd :

```
int iError = reinterpret_cast<int>(lParam);
int iWorks = (int)lParam;
```

I get a C2440 error on the first:
error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'LPARAM' to 'int'

but the 2nd one compiles fine

This is C++, not C, hence I prefer the first over the second.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does static_cast not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` validates that it can re-interpret the underlying bit structure at compile time, and it sees that you're trying to change a `LPARAM` to `int` and doesn't like it.

Try `static_cast` instead.

Further information: `LPARAM` is [defined as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) `LONG_PTR` which itself is:

```cpp
#if defined(_WIN64)
 typedef __int64 LONG_PTR; 
#else
 typedef long LONG_PTR;
#endif
```

Comment: Since this is compiling for 32 bit, a LONG should convert to an int with no issue, so reinterpret_cast should work?

Comment: @franji1 No, `long` is not required to be the same size than `int` and is a separate type on its own. So, `reinterpret_cast` cannot allow that even if the sizes match for your platform/build (as already suggested, `static_cast` is made for this purpose).

Comment: @franji1 no. [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) cannot be used for conversions from one integer type to another integer type, [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) is used for that instead. Always try `static_cast` first, and then `reinterpret_cast` only if needed. A [C-style cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) tries `static_cast` before `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: I loathe c-style casts in C++.  `static_cast` it is!

Comment: Mind you, a `static_cast` is still dangerous, even when compiling for 32 bits. `LPARAM` could store a pointer after all (that's what it was initially intended for). Converting that to a *signed* `int` can subsequently introduce very subtle bugs, depending on the operations performed on the result.

Comment: @IInspectable  Yes, and that's the caveat when dealing with Windows Message signatures, WPARAM and LPARAM can be ANYTHING.  My specific windows message (it's a user message) has that parameter documented, but like you said, anyone could send that message with any LPARAM, but that is true of EVERY WM_* windows message, not just this one.  In my situation, it's an enum, and I am checking for the specific equivalent values 0, 1, 2, where 0 (LPARAM default) means don't do anything extra (1 and 2 do something extra).