# reinterpret_cast invalid but static_cast is fine

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

I am new to explicit casts in C++. I thought that static_cast was way more restrictive than reinterpret_cast. However, I have a function where static_cast gives me the desired result and reinterpret_cast tells me that my conversion is invalid. Why is this happening?

```
void    from_int(int x)
{
    if (x < 32 || x > 126)
        std::cout << "char: Non displayable" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "char: '" << reinterpret_cast<char>(x) << "'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "float: " << x << ".0f" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "double: " << x << ".0" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I mis-interpreted reinterpret_cast the same as a C-style cast, but it is not.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602983/why-does-reinterpret-castintlparam-generate-c2440-error

Answer (score 4):

`static_cast` is more restrictive than `reinterpret_cast` when performing a cast from one pointer type to another. With `reinterpret_cast`, such a cast will always compile (assuming the cast is from object pointer to object pointer or function pointer to function pointer).

`reinterpret_cast` is narrowly tailored to such pointer casts, analogous reference casts, and casts between pointer and integer types. What you want to do here is perform an *implicit conversion*. In such cases, as well as when you want to perform the *reverse* of an implicit conversion, `static_cast` is usually the correct choice. Some programmers use a user-defined "`implicit_cast`" template which is even weaker than `static_cast`, but safer (it only performs implicit conversions).